# Python ast parsing exception

Tags: python-2.7, abstract-syntax-tree, python-3.4

I was using ast module of python3.4 to get the imports and function calls within a file.

It works correctly if I run the code on a file which has python3.4 syntax but throws an exception if I try to parse a file of older python2.7 version (for print statements, except statements which have a "," etc).

Is there a way to force ast to use python2.7 compiler while dealing with old files and use python3.4 compiler when dealing with python3.4 file?
Is there any other way to resolve this issue??

Comment: A Python3 interpreter does not contain a Python2 parser (and vice-versa). If I was hard pressed to do this, I'd run a subordinate `multiprocessing` instance of a Python 2 interpreter. I'm pretty sure the AST between the two versions are not congruent, so you'd have to write a v2.7 version of your v3.x AST extraction code.

Comment: Any examples of how to do this? I have tested my AST code and it works for both version individually. Currently I am trying to run code from v2.7 , and want to somehow create the tree using v3.4 ast parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is not possible to use different versions of AST parsers in python to the best of my knowledge. (It is still possible to parse them separately by carrying out multiple iterations each time using a different version AST)